# How to make discord.js bots check if the channel is NSFW and reply?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make my discord bot send different messages when anyone types a command in a normal channel or NSFW channels.

I followed the documentation, which I didn't quite get it. I wrote the testing commands below:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (command === 'testnsfw') {
        if (this.nsfw = Boolean(true.nsfw)) {
            return message.channel.send('yes NSFW');
        } else return message.channel.send('no NSFW');
    }
})
```

I think it is not working. The bot only responds "no NSFW" on both channels.

Comment: Try `this.nsfw === Boolean(true.nsfw)`; single `=` for assignment, double or triple for testing (value or value and type respectively).

Comment: `message.channel.nsfw` returns a boolean

Answer (score 2):

You cannot refer to the [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel) using `this` in the anonymous function. (Also, `this` is always `undefined` in an arrow function) You can access the [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel) using the [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) class, stored in the `message` variable.

---

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    // Making the sure the author of the message is not a bot.
    // Without this line, the code will create an infinite loop of messages, because even if a message is sent by a bot account, the client will emit the message event.
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    // message.content is a String, containing the entire content of the message.
    // Before checking if it equals to "testnsfw", I would suggest to transform it to lowercase first.
    // So "testNSFW", "testnsfw", "TeStNsFw", etc.. will pass the if statement.
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "testnsfw") {
        // You can get the Channel class (which contains the nsfw property) using the Message class.
        if (message.channel.nsfw) {
            message.channel.send("This channel is NSFW.");
        } else {
            message.channel.send("This channel is SFW.");
        }
    }
});
```

---

#### What I encourage you to read:

- [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message)
- [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel)

Answer (score 0):

now you can just do this instead

```
if(!message.channel.nsfw) return message.channel.send('a message to send to channel')
```

this is using
discord.js verson 13.6.0

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in DiscordJS V14

```
if(interaction.channel?.type==ChannelType.GuildText)
{
   await interaction.reply({ content: `Is NSFW: ${interaction.channel.nsfw}` })
}
```